# How to create custom gradle plugin for Android application

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How to create custom gradle plugin for Android application?

Which language is best for creating custom plugin for Android app development purposes and can be used in Gradle build file for building process?

Comment: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/02/gce2retrofit-gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add your code to `buildSrc` module. For a Groovy plugin the directory will be `buildSrc/src/main/groovy`.

```
package com.example;

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
   ...
}
```

and then from your `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
import com.example.MyPlugin

android { 
    ...
}
```